# Tried to code an integer compare method and it's not working

Tags: c, arrays, loops, int

I have an array of integers and I'm trying to find which one is the highest and set a new integer to the highest ones value. I'm very new to C, I literally just started learning it.

There is probably some kind of logical problem with what I'm doing but I haven't been able to spot it yet. so...

```
int my_array[4];
int highest_int = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (my_array[i] > my_array[i++]) {
        if (my_array[i] > highest_int) {
            highest_int = my_array[i];
        }
    }
    else {
        if (my_array[i++] > highest_int) {
            highest_int = my_array[i++]
        }
    }
}
```

So I loop through my array 4 times (4 elements) and I look at the iteration value and the next one and if the iteration value is highest I check it's also higher than the current value of the current 'highest integer' and if it is I set the current highest integer to the new highest value. If the value after the iteration value is higher I do the same thing but with that value instead.

That's what went through my head when I wrote this but when I enter 4 values it always comes out with the 3rd value in the array. No matter what I set those values to.

Can anyone tell me why?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: For one, you are doing i++ in your array indexing, which does i = i + 1. Instead, you really just want to be doing my_array[i + 1].

Comment: `my_array[i] > my_array[i++]` is undefined behaviour, use `i+1`.

Comment: Also, all the tests except `my_array[i] > highest_int` are redundant.

Comment: `i+1` is wrong too, that `if` statement should just be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're making this way more complicated than it really is :) Furthermore, you're writing `i++` in too many places; each time `i++` gets executed you're skipping over an array entry, which is probably not what you want.

Also, there's no need to compare to the previous value. Just compare to the highest one you've seen so far.

Here's a fixed version, just by deleting code, nothing changed or added:

```
int my_array[4];
int highest_int = 0;
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    if (my_array[i] > highest_int) {
        highest_int = my_array[i];
    }
}
```

Note that this incorrectly reports 0 if all numbers in the array are negative. Start off `highest_int = INT_MIN` in case you need to handle those correctly, or use `unsigned int`.

Comment: How can you assume there is no negative number in the array? Isnt it better to have highest_int as the first element and continue the comparisions?

Comment: When looking for the maximum, we don't want to set `highest_int = INT_MAX`, because nothing will ever be bigger and we'd always return `INT_MAX`. We really need to start with `INT_MIN`, which is the correct answer even if all array entries are equal to `INT_MIN`.

Answer (score 6):

Why you are incrementing `i` inside the loop? Why do you need the else part?

Here's a simple way:

```
int my_array[4];
int highest_int = my_array[0];
int i;

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
        if (my_array[i] > highest_int) {
            highest_int = my_array[i];
        }
    }
```

Comment: +1 for using the first element of the array as the starting highest value.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to find the highest number, here is the code:

```
int my_array[4];
int highest_int = my_array[0]; 
//Before entering the loop, assuming the first number to  highest
int i;

for (i = 1; i < 4; i++) {
    if (my_array[i] > highest_int) {  //Compare every number with highest number
        highest_int = my_array[i];
    }  
}

//Now we have the highest number
printf("Highest Number: %d",highest_int);
```